# Can I see object sent from ajax to php in php with a debugger?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem, I make an ajax call to a php file and I send a json object as a param from ajax/javascript to php, then php is supposed to do some logic with that object and return it with echo `json_encode('whatever');` 
My problem is when I'm working with the javascript object in php I'm blind, because my ajax call only have the success or the error function to "know" what hapenned in php, but I would like to know what mechanism can I use to see what happens inside php, like for example print the object received from ajax and see whatever is inside of it. How can I debug when I'm inside a php file called from ajax?? I've tryed chrome debuger and also firebug, and followed both tutorials, but I don't even see the php file that is called from ajax, so I can't set breakpoints into it. This is my code to do the ajax call to my php file and my php file that echos whatever information back:

```
function loadFormAdvanced(advancedFormVars) {
    var json = new Array();
    json = '[';
    for (var prop in advancedFormVars) {
        if (advancedFormVars.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            // or if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj,prop)) for safety...
            json += '{"' + prop + ":" + advancedFormVars[prop] + '},';
        }
    }
    json += ']';


    $.ajax({
        url: 'AL_loadForm.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            advancedFormVars: json //"[{"OfferID:"OfferID"},{"offerName:"Offer Name"},{"campaignID:"CampaignID"},{"campaignName:"CampaignName"},{"offerIDFilt:"OfferID"},{"dates:"Dates"},]"
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("Error: please fill the required fields");
        }
    });
}
```

What I would like is to be abble to see what happens in my php file, or for example, to see the content of `$val` variable.

Comment: `if($_POST['advancedFormVars']){` change to this key.

Comment: this was a error typing, I've editted

Comment: also set a proper json content header from the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to log PHP side:

```
file_put_contents('somepath/dbg_'.date('Y-m-d').'.log',var_export($value,true));
```

A path that is write able in php - so it can create the dbg_date.log or what ever file name you want.
value would be whatever is in your post or what you are trying to debug.

There are also plugins like firebug or chromephp.

Comment: Should add that  the true for var_export allows it to return variable instead of trying to output it in the browser.

Chrome logger can be included in your project and used to log into console. I renamed the class to console so i can do console::log($var);

Answer (score 0):

Display the object in the java Script console of your browser:

```
success : function(data) {
    console.log(data);
},
```

I usually open the ajax URL manually with the browser for debugging purposes. That also works

But I think I misunderstood your question at first. You want to see the content of the sent object `json`, but just do the same:

```
console.log(json); // after the object has been created
```

Comment: Yes that is a way to do it, but can't I print variables from php or what is the same, watch the php code from the debuger to see what happens inside of this code?

Comment: You mean php's functions `print_r` or `var_dump` ?

Comment: yes, exactly, what can I do if I need to see var contents ?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST('advancedFormVars'));`

Comment: this will result in a ajax error function without anything printed in the screen

Comment: There is not much more I can do for you. I'm still not so sure what you're trying to achieve :-)... I'm not gonna debug your php file ;-)

Comment: no thank you, it's me who wants to debug my php file but I don't know how to, if I do soemthing like print_r, vardump, or echo from ajax it will not output anything to the screen, except if the echo is json_encoded and the ajax call has json as datatype param, it's very basic what I want to do, just output some data from my php file, but since it's called from ajax, it has to be done by a diferent way, otherwise it will enter in ajax error function